# Does setting the selected item of a UITabBar calls tabBar:didSelectItem method?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Everything is in the title. I would like to know if setting the selected item of a `UITabBar` like that :

```
tabBar.selectedItem = tabBar.items![0]
```

Calls the `UITabBarDelegate` method `tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem)`
?
It doesn't look like it does, but I sometimes have some issues in my code and I was wondering if this could be related..

Comment: Did you put a breakpoint in didSelectItem and see if it is called or not ?

Comment: Yes, it gets called, but that's probably some other issue then. I'll investigate, thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it does not.

The [UITabBarDelegate docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarDelegate_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITabBarDelegate/tabBar:didSelectItem:) states:

> Sent to the delegate when the **user** selects a tab bar item.